# *New to SQL* RIGHT and LEFT functions not pulling the same reflective results based on the same POSITION

Tags: postgresql, position

[Picture of what i tried with results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MamHB.jpg)
Could someone make sense of why the LEFT syntax pulls different results than the RIGHT syntax when the same exact POSITION is used? Even in the RIGHT result column almost every entry is different, why is this?

I attached a picture of what i did. The column referenced is full of emails. The POSITION I use is '@'. With the LEFT syntax I want to pull the name of the person and with the RIGHT I want to pull what is left of the email address.

I'm new to this and using postgres SQL trying to learn and the information I'm using is just for learning purposes.

Thank you all in advance!!!

Comment: I don't click on random links posted by strangers on the internet and neither do many other people on the site. You have a much better chance of getting help if you follow the guidelines and post the text of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html),

> `right(str text, n int)` - Return last n characters in the string.
> When n is negative, return all but first |n| characters.
>
> `left(str text, n int)`  - Return first n characters in the string.
> When n is negative, return all but last |n| characters.

Extraction:

The first part (First n characters minus '@' character) : `POSITION('@' IN email_id) - 1`

The second part(Length last n characters): `LENGTH(email_id) - POSITION('@' IN email_id)`

```
SELECT 
    email_id,
    LEFT(email_id, POSITION('@' IN email_id) - 1) AS username,
    RIGHT(email_id, LENGTH(email_id) - POSITION('@' IN email_id)) AS domain
FROM your_table;
```